Graph node coloring with minimal distance within same group
I have a list of edges with weights (node1 node2 weight) as an input for an undirected graph.
A B 10
A C 9
A D 2
B C 1

I also have a list of colors as input like below:
Red: 2
Blue: 2

Let's say we define distance of 2 nodes is the shortest path between nodes A and B is denoted by dist(A,B). Notation c is the list of unique colors. In the example, c=[red, blue]
Sum of distance of pair of nodes within the same group is denoted like this: Ired,
Iblue, etc.
Sum of distance of pair of nodes between one group to another is denoted like this: Ered,blue 
After assigning the colors to nodes, the solution is evaluated by the following equation:

If we pick B, C to be Red in the above example and A, D to be blue, the score would be:
Ired=1
Ired=2
Ered,blue=dist(A,B)+dist(A,C)+dist(D,B)+dist(D,C)=10+9+12+11=42
Score=4/5(1+2)+1/5(42)=2.4+8.4=10.8
I'm looking for an algorithm that assigns colors to nodes in a way, that the calculated score is minimal. I believe finding global optimum is not possible with polynomial complexity, but the algorithm should find a good approximation at least.

What is c in your summations?

c is the list of colors. In the example, c=[red, blue]. I’ll edit this to my question

You could build the matrix of pairwise node distances and then use either k-medoids or integer programming or some other clustering methods


We can create a data structure for the nodes, weights, and edges of the graph.
We initialize the distance matrix with infinite values and zeros on the diagonal and fill the matrix with the weights.
We compute the shortest paths among all nodes using Floyd-Warshall.
We calculate the score based on the equation.
We use a heuristic method to find a good coloring of the nodes that minimizes the score.

Code
import numpy as np
import random
from collections import defaultdict


def _graph(edges):
    weights, nodes = defaultdict(int), set()
    for a, b, w in edges:
        nodes.update({a, b})
        weights[(a, b)] = w
        weights[(b, a)] = w
    return list(nodes), weights


def _dist(nodes, weights):
    n = len(nodes)
    dist = np.full((n, n), np.inf)
    for i in range(n):
        dist[i, i] = 0
    for (a, b), w in weights.items():
        i, j = nodes.index(a), nodes.index(b)
        dist[i, j] = w
    return dist


def floyd_warshall(n, dist):
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if dist[i, j] > dist[i, k] + dist[k, j]:
                    dist[i, j] = dist[i, k] + dist[k, j]
    return dist


def get_score(coloring, dist, nodes):
    I = {'R': 0, 'B': 0}
    E = 0
    i_colors = {
        'R': [i for i, c in enumerate(coloring) if c == 'R'],
        'B': [i for i, c in enumerate(coloring) if c == 'B']
    }
    for c in i_colors:
        inds = i_colors[c]
        for i in range(len(inds)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(inds)):
                I[c] += dist[inds[i], inds[j]]
    for i in i_colors['R']:
        for j in i_colors['B']:
            E += dist[i, j]
    equation = 0.8 * (I['R'] + I['B']) + 0.2 * E
    return equation


def get_heuristic(nodes, colors, dist):
    res_coloring = None
    res_score = float('inf')
    colors = ['R'] * colors['R'] + ['B'] * colors['B']
    random.seed(17)
    random.shuffle(colors)
    for _ in range(100):
        random.shuffle(colors)
        curr = get_score(colors, dist, nodes)
        if curr < res_score:
            res_score = curr
            res_coloring = colors[:]
    return res_coloring, res_score


def main():
    edges = (('A', 'B', 10), ('A', 'C', 9), ('A', 'D', 2), ('B', 'C', 1))
    colors = {'R': 2, 'B': 2}
    nodes, weights = _graph(edges)
    dist = _dist(nodes, weights)
    dist = floyd_warshall(len(nodes), dist)
    coloring, score = get_heuristic(nodes, colors, dist)
    res = dict(zip(nodes, coloring))
    return res, score


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())


Prints
({'A': 'B', 'D': 'B', 'C': 'R', 'B': 'R'}, 10.8)

We can also use Dijkstra or other similar graph algorithms:
import numpy as np
import random
import heapq
from collections import defaultdict, deque


def _graph(edges):
    weights, nodes = defaultdict(dict), set()
    for a, b, w in edges:
        nodes.update({a, b})
        weights[a][b] = w
        weights[b][a] = w
    return list(nodes), weights


def dijkstra(n, nodes, weights):
    dist = np.full((n, n), np.inf)
    for i in range(n):
        dist[i, i] = 0
        source = nodes[i]
        Q = [(0, source)]
        seen = set()
        while Q:
            curr_dist, u = heapq.heappop(Q)
            if u in seen:
                continue
            seen.add(u)
            u_idx = nodes.index(u)
            for v, w in weights[u].items():
                v_idx = nodes.index(v)
                if dist[i, v_idx] > curr_dist + w:
                    dist[i, v_idx] = curr_dist + w
                    heapq.heappush(Q, (dist[i, v_idx], v))
    return dist


def get_score(coloring, dist, nodes):
    I = {'R': 0, 'B': 0}
    E = 0
    i_colors = {
        'R': [i for i, c in enumerate(coloring) if c == 'R'],
        'B': [i for i, c in enumerate(coloring) if c == 'B']
    }
    for c in i_colors:
        inds = i_colors[c]
        for i in range(len(inds)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(inds)):
                I[c] += dist[inds[i], inds[j]]
    for i in i_colors['R']:
        for j in i_colors['B']:
            E += dist[i, j]
    equation = 0.8 * (I['R'] + I['B']) + 0.2 * E
    return equation


def get_heuristic(nodes, colors, dist):
    res_coloring = None
    res_score = float('inf')
    colors = ['R'] * colors['R'] + ['B'] * colors['B']
    random.seed(17)
    random.shuffle(colors)
    for _ in range(100):
        random.shuffle(colors)
        curr = get_score(colors, dist, nodes)
        if curr < res_score:
            res_score = curr
            res_coloring = colors[:]
    return res_coloring, res_score


def main():
    edges = (('A', 'B', 10), ('A', 'C', 9), ('A', 'D', 2), ('B', 'C', 1))
    colors = {'R': 2, 'B': 2}
    nodes, weights = _graph(edges)
    dist = dijkstra(len(nodes), nodes, weights)
    coloring, score = get_heuristic(nodes, colors, dist)
    res = dict(zip(nodes, coloring))
    return res, score


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())



I don’t think this would give a good approximation for ideal solution with graphs where node count is larger than in the example, for example a graph with 1-200 nodes.
